# Spring Boot return only one random document from MongoDB Collection

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Imagine I have three documents in collection:

First one is:

```
Title: Myanmar
Category: escortedTours
```

Second one is:

```
Title: Barcelona
Category: independentTours
```

Third one is:

```
Title: Spain
Category: escortedTours
```

Now I want to create a method that will return me just **ONE RANDOM**  document with `category` as `escortedTours`. So for every refresh page program need to return me one random document with `escortedTours`.

I create something like this but this return me all documents with `category` as `escortedTours` while I need one random element on every refresh.

`Repo:`

`List<PackageHoliday> findByTypeOfPackageHoliday(String typeOfPackageHoliday);`

`ServiceImpl:`

```
 @Override
public List<PackageHoliday> findByTypeOfPackageHoliday(String typeOfPackageHoliday) {
    return packageHolidayRepository.findByTypeOfPackageHoliday(typeOfPackageHoliday);
}
```

And `controller:`

```
  @GetMapping("/getEscortedTours")
public List<PackageHoliday> getByPackageHoliday() {
    return packageHolidayService.findByTypeOfPackageHoliday("escortedTours");
}
```

What and where I need to add/create so this will return me just one random document from collection with category as `escortedTours`

Answer (score 0):

Try the [$sample](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) operator:

```
db.PackageHoliday.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      Category: "escortedTours"
    }
  },
  {
    $sample: {
      size: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bAFL-5--niT)